# It seems my 'new.html.erb' file does not rerender

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to display errors conditionally.

Here are my two files
`new.html.erb`

```
<h1>Create a New Article</h1>
<% if @article.errors.any? %>
  <h2>Please fix the following errors</h2>
  <ul>
    <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>


<%= form_with scope: :article, url: articles_path, local: true do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %>  <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %>  <br/>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

and `articles_controller.rb`

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end
    def index
        @articles = Article.all
    end
    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end
    def create
        @article = Article.new(params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description))
        if @article.save
            redirect_to @article
        else 
            puts @article.errors.any?
            render 'new'
        end
    end
end
```

In my `def create` action I want to rerender my `new.html.erb` which should display errors. For some reason I don't think it rerenders.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What error do you expect on create? What does your model look like?

Comment: You should see the errors. Yet the form may not repopulate correctly as you only use `scope` instead of `model`. Try to change `scope: :article` by `model: @article`

Comment: @Maxence thanks for the input but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out with help from some people on Udemy. In Rails 7 we have to add `status: :unprocessable_entity` after the `render new` like so

```
def create
        @article = Article.new(params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description))
        if @article.save
            redirect_to @article
        else 
            puts @article.errors.any?
            render 'new', status: :unprocessable_entity 
        end
    end
```